# SQL Server row Name increment

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Hi SQL Server experts,

I have a problem that might be easy for most of you, but I really do not know how to solve it. I have 2 tables, one is called Sites, and one is called meters. The Sites table can have one or more meters. When I do this join:

```
SELECT * FROM Sites
JOIN Meters
WHERE Sites.ID = Meters.SiteID
WHERE Sites.ID = 1
```

I get the following:

```
ID SiteName SiteID MeterName
1 Site1 1 Meter1
1 Site1 1 Meter2
1 Site1 1 Meter3
```

Now, I need to copy the data from these two tables to new tables... I already have the code for that but I am not sure how to do the following: I want to do a loop for @MeterName so that it would loop and assign the meters different names as long as there are meters in a site! In the code below, it will give me Meter 1 for all the meters which I do not want.

```
Declare @MeterName varchar(20) = 'Meter 1'
        @SiteID int = 1

INSERT INTO METER (MeterName, SiteID)
SELECT @MeterName, @SiteID
```

I tried the following loop but I am not sure how to write this in the select statement after the insert:

```
DECLARE @Name varchar (20) = 'Meter',
        @MeterNumber int = 1,
        @TheMetername varchar(20)

WHILE (@MeterNumber <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Sites
    WHERE SiteID = 1)

BEGIN
SET  @TheMetername = @Name + ' ' + cast(@MeterNumber as varchar(20))
PRINT @Name + ' ' + cast(@MeterNumber as varchar(20))
SET  @MeterNumber = @MeterNumber + 1
END

  INSERT INTO METER (MeterName, SiteID)
    SELECT @MeterName, @SiteID
```

How can I do this problem? Is there any other way than loops?

Comment: Post desired output for the new table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since siteId=1 , substitute @SiteId with 1 while inserting . Put the INSERT statement inside WHILE loop

```
WHILE (@MeterNumber <= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Sites
    WHERE SiteID = 1)


BEGIN
SET  @TheMetername = @Name + ' ' + cast(@MeterNumber as varchar(20))
PRINT @Name + ' ' + cast(@MeterNumber as varchar(20))

INSERT INTO METER (MeterName, SiteID) VALUES( @MeterName, 1)

SET  @MeterNumber = @MeterNumber + 1
END
```

Comment: Would you please check my code that I edited? Thank you so much.